# Android TabLayout inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout

I am using `Navigation Drawer` to navigate between fragments they all use the MainActivity toolbar but each fragment has it's own `TabLayout` with 3 tabs and in each tab I am using `RecyclerView` to show different text and images.

I did this last time using actvities instead of fragments but now using the drawer it's beter to use fragments.

I have got to a point where the tabs work but as soon as I put the `ViewPager` in and connect the adapters to the tabs and I open the new fragment from the drawer I get a Null Pointer what could be the problem here?

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity

    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    return id == R.id.action_settings || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Fragment fragment;

    if (id == R.id.fragment_one) {
        fragment = new NewFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
        ft.commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.fragment_two) {

        fragment = new NewFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
        ft.commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.fragment_three) {

        fragment = new NewFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
        ft.commit();

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.xcandy.guideforfifa17.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

NewFragment.java

```
public class NewFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment_one, container, false);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("A"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("B"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("C"));

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);


    viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter
            (getFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount()));
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    return view;
}

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }



    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:

                RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter = new AdapterOne();
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            case 1:

                mAdapter = new AdapterTwo();
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            case 2:

                mAdapter = new AdapterThree();
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
}
```

activity_fragment.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".NewFragment">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Error Log

```
                  --------- beginning of crash
06-23 11:19:56.985 2466-2466/com.candyx.sims E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: com.candyx.sims, PID: 2466
                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
                                                                   at com.candyx.sims.BlankFragment.onCreateView(BlankFragment.java:38)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
06-23 11:23:14.912 5839-5873/com.candyx.sims D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

                                                               [ 06-23 11:23:14.920  5839: 5839 D/         ]
                                                               HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb4125190, tid 5839
06-23 11:23:14.927 5839-5839/com.candyx.sims D/Atlas: Validating map...
06-23 11:23:15.011 5839-5873/com.candyx.sims I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-23 11:23:15.027 5839-5873/com.candyx.sims D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
06-23 11:23:15.039 5839-5873/com.candyx.sims W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-23 11:23:15.039 5839-5873/com.candyx.sims W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xae838600, error=EGL_SUCCESS
06-23 11:23:16.444 5839-5839/com.candyx.sims W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000596046461
06-23 11:23:17.342 5839-5839/com.candyx.sims W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000596046461
06-23 11:23:17.350 5839-5839/com.candyx.sims I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
06-23 11:23:17.369 5839-5839/com.candyx.sims D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-23 11:23:17.369 5839-5839/com.candyx.sims E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: com.candyx.sims, PID: 5839
                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
                                                                   at com.candyx.sims.NewFragment.onCreateView(NewFragment.java:38)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
06-23 11:25:16.961 7518-7518/com.candyx.sims W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
06-23 11:25:17.078 7518-7548/com.candyx.sims D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

                                                               [ 06-23 11:25:17.081  7518: 7518 D/         ]
                                                               HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb412a1f0, tid 7518
06-23 11:25:17.082 7518-7518/com.candyx.sims D/Atlas: Validating map...
06-23 11:25:17.109 7518-7548/com.candyx.sims I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-23 11:25:17.126 7518-7548/com.candyx.sims D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
06-23 11:25:17.134 7518-7548/com.candyx.sims W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-23 11:25:17.134 7518-7548/com.candyx.sims W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb41234c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
06-23 11:25:31.030 7518-7518/com.candyx.sims W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000596046461
06-23 11:25:32.174 7518-7518/com.candyx.sims W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000596046461
06-23 11:25:32.187 7518-7518/com.candyx.sims I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
06-23 11:25:32.207 7518-7518/com.candyx.sims D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-23 11:25:32.207 7518-7518/com.candyx.sims E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: com.candyx.sims, PID: 7518
                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
                                                                   at com.candyx.sims.NewFragment.onCreateView(NewFragment.java:38)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: add error logs in question

Comment: Please show `activity_main.xml` too

Comment: You wanna create nested fragments using `TabLayout` and`ViewPager`

Comment: what is the error log you getting, please post it

Comment: There is problem there is one shadow between toolbar and tablayout when fragment is loaded.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

After looking into yours code, I found that you forget to return a fragment in **getItem** method of PagerAdapter that you overrided from the FragmentStatePagerAdapter and there is no break statement in each case due to which every time a null value was returned.

To doing so you need to create a another new fragment for each page in ViewPager or you can create one new fragment that could use in all page of ViewPager.

You can't use the same recyclerview into the tabs of view pager that you have defined in parent fragment.

activity_fragment_one.xml

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".NewFragment">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:tabTextAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            app:tabTextColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I have fixed your fragment and created a new Fragment that you can use in ViewPager Pages.

```
public class NewFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment_one, container, false);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("A"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("B"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("C"));
    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
   // mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    //mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount()));
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    return view;
}

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
              return new FragmentTab();
            case 1:
                return new FragmentTab();
            case 2:
                return new FragmentTab();

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
}
```

FragmentTab for each Page in View Pager (or you can create different fragment for each page according to yours need).

```
public class FragmentTab extends Fragment {
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab, container, false);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter = new AdapterOne();
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    return view;
}
}
```

fragment_tab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi there, I followed this approach but the content inside the fragment_tab is not visible in my case.

Answer (score 10):

Use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: This is work for me. I replace from `getFragmentManager()` to `getChildFragmentManager()`. Finally, the recyclerview is showed.

Answer (score 5):

i suggest using `getChildFragmentManager` instead of `getFragmentManager` in

`viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter
            (getFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount()));`

Comment: yeah, this was all I needed

Comment: Solved. I get it with this.

Answer (score 2):

Without the error logs, it's difficult to say where and why do you get the `NullPointerException`.

The first thing that caught my attention is that you didn't link your `TabLayout` and `ViewPager`. Use the following code after you set the adapter for the `ViewPager`:

```
// setUpWithViewPager doesn't work without using a Runnable interface.
// Support library bug, maybe?
tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
});
```

I'm not sure if this is the problem, but give it a try :)

Comment: After I call tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager); - Tabs names disappers

Comment: @tieorange Could you post your code? Use codepen.io or pastebin.com

Answer (score 1):

Well, some time ago I implemented exactly the same app design. I had a fragment, that intended to hold Tabs and ViewPager. That was a tricky task, and I recall that I faced similar problems as you did. Here is how I solved it:

The layout sequence is:

`Activity -> Fragment -> Tab Layout + ViewPager -> FragmentStatePagerAdapter -> Fragment -> RecyclerView`

You've got nothing to do with your Main Activity. All the stuff is in fragments. So get rid from TabLayout in your `activity_main.xml`.

**You will have to deal with nested fragments inside pager. All page content must be there and TabLayout must be in the same layout where you ViewPager is.**

My project is a bit old, and I used `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` in case if it makes sense. I stripped sources from data you wont need, so you may see refers to some orphaned methods.

The task was to display price list with categories, and render each category products on its own page, so that horizontal swipes would switch categories and vertical swipes — list products.

Each fragment with ViewPager and TabLayout has following `subfragment_price_list_pager.xml` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/icons"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/priceListToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar.TabLayout"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_tag_multiple_grey600_24dp"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/priceList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal" />


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Here is the `PriceListPagerFragment.class`:

```
public class PriceListPagerFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "PriceListPagerFragment";
    private PriceList mPriceList;

    private ViewPager mCategoriesViewPager;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;

    private Loader<PriceList> priceListLoader;
    private EditText scanerBarcodeText;
    private OnCartActionListener mListener;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.subfragment_price_list_pager, container, false);

        // Pager that would be inflated with page fragments.
        mCategoriesViewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.priceList);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabBar);
        tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);

        // Do all the stuff with pager here:
        updatePriceListPages();

        return rootView;
    }


    private void updatePriceListPages() {
        if (mCategoriesViewPager != null && mPriceList != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, this + "updatePriceListPages");
            if (mCategoriesViewPager.getAdapter() == null) {


                PriceListCategoriesAdapter adapter = new PriceListCategoriesAdapter(
                        getFragmentManager(),
                        tabLayout
                );
                mCategoriesViewPager.setAdapter(
                        adapter
                );
                // Each page is a content of a single category of one-level catalog 
                // We did not supply catalog to adapter before it is bound to ViewPager for some serious reason which I can't recall now 
                adapter.setPriceList(mPriceList);

                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mCategoriesViewPager);
            } else {
                ((PriceListCategoriesAdapter) mCategoriesViewPager.getAdapter()).setPriceList(mPriceList);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Custom `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` implementation, `PriceListCategoriesAdapter.class`:

```
public class PriceListCategoriesAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private static final String TAG = "PriceListCategoriesAd";
    private final TabLayout mTabLayout;
    private FragmentManager mFm;
    private Vector<PriceListFragment> recyclerViewList;
    private Vector<String> titles;

    public PriceListCategoriesAdapter(FragmentManager fm, TabLayout tabLayout) {
        super(fm);
        mFm = fm;
        mTabLayout = tabLayout;
        recyclerViewList = new Vector<>();
        titles = new Vector<>();
    }


    // All the magic with nested page fragments is done here
    public void setPriceList(PriceList priceList) {
        boolean updateTabs = false;

        Vector<String> newTitles = new Vector<>();

        int position = 0;
        for (CatalogItem catalogItem : priceList.getCatalogs()) {

            if (catalogItem.getProducts() == null)
                continue;

            boolean newFragment;

            PriceListFragment fragment;
            try {
                fragment = recyclerViewList.get(position);
                newFragment = false;

            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                fragment = new PriceListFragment();
                newFragment = true;
            }

            fragment.setCatalogItem(catalogItem);

            newTitles.add(catalogItem.getName());

            if (newFragment) {
                recyclerViewList.add(fragment);
            }
            position++;
        }

        if (titles.size() != newTitles.size()) {
            updateTabs = true;
        } else {
            for (int position = 0; position < titles.size(); position++) {
                if (!titles.get(position).equals(newTitles.get(position))) {
                    updateTabs = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        titles = newTitles;
        notifyDataSetChanged();

        if (updateTabs)
            mTabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(this);
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return recyclerViewList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        PriceListFragment fragment = (PriceListFragment) object;
        String title = (String) fragment.getTitle();
        int position = titles.indexOf(title);

        if (position >= 0) {
            return position;
        } else {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return titles.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return recyclerViewList.get(position).getTitle();
    }

    // We don't keep states
    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }
    // We don't keep states
    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
    }
}
```

And finally `PriceListFragment` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView android:id="@+id/categoryList"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

`PriceListFragment.class` itself has nothing special. Just instantiate it's RecyclerView with proper data.

Answer (score 0):

This method `getItem` in `PagerAdapter` wrong, it return `Fragment` init
You should return `Fragment`. And in fragment, you `setView` `recyclerView` to it

Answer (score 0):

**Creating the tabLayout and viewpager2 inside the container solves the problem

on clicking HomePage from Navigation Drawer : remove all the fragments
and display tablayout and viewPager2
otherwise hide tablayout and viewpager2 and load the fragment
**

***XML FILE***

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainPageActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start"

    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme" />


        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:id="@+id/tabLayoutMainPage"/>

                <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/viewPager2MainPage"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"></androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2>
            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_items"

        />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

***Activity JAVA File***

```
package com.example.myultimateapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayoutMediator;

public class MainPageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager2 viewPager2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);


        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        @SuppressLint("ResourceType") ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.openNavigation, R.string.closeNavigation);

        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);

        toggle.syncState();


        tabLayout = drawerLayout.findViewById(R.id.container).findViewById(R.id.tabLayoutMainPage);
        viewPager2 = drawerLayout.findViewById(R.id.container).findViewById(R.id.viewPager2MainPage);


        ViewPager2Adapter adapter = new ViewPager2Adapter(this, MainPageActivity.this);
        viewPager2.setAdapter(adapter);

        new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager2, new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {
                tab.setText(ViewPager2Adapter.getPageTitle(position));

            }
        }).attach();


        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                int id = item.getItemId();

                switch (id) {
                    case R.id.navigationItemHomePage:

                        findViewById(R.id.tabLayoutMainPage).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        findViewById(R.id.viewPager2MainPage).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);




                        for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
                            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                            ft.remove(fragment).commit();
                        }

                        break;
                    case R.id.navigationItemLogOut:
                        Toast.makeText(MainPageActivity.this, "Logging out TODO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigationItemYourProfile:
                        Toast.makeText(MainPageActivity.this, "Your Profile TODO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigationItemJokesPage: {
                        loadFragment(new JokesFragment(MainPageActivity.this), 1);
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.navigationItemActivities: {
                        loadFragment(new ActivitiesFragment(MainPageActivity.this), 1);
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.navigationItemDogImages: {
                        loadFragment(new DogImagesFragment(MainPageActivity.this), 1);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START))
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        else
            super.onBackPressed();

    }


    private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment, int flag) {
        findViewById(R.id.tabLayoutMainPage).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.viewPager2MainPage).setVisibility(View.GONE);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

        if (flag == 0)
            ft.add(R.id.container, fragment);
        else
            ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```