# Is There any Possible to Achieve Use SlideMenu With TabView In Android Studio

Tags: android, menu, tabs, fragment, swipe

Actually i'm designing one app now.
Slide menu control, this menu have 5 categories like 5 fragments.

Each fragment have different different datas.I implemented slide menu also working perfectly.

Here first fragment is home fragment,In that i need to use tab swipe view control i mean two tabs will be there like tab names recent and all tabs. 
So when i press recent tab needs to show something and when  i press all tab needs to show something.

But here i don't know how to use i researched for lot but i didn't get those.

What i exactly need is in slide menu home fragment i need tab based fragment

[For your reference this screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DJCp.png)

I need those codes please.And let me know is it possible or not.

Thanks in advance

this is my home fragment

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
  View view;
  private TabLayout tabLayout;
  private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
     view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    return view;
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new 
    ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new MoviesFragment(), "ONE");
    adapter.addFragment(new PhotosFragment(), "TWO");
    adapter.addFragment(new SettingsFragment(), "THREE");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

  class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

These Fragments are for tab

```
adapter.addFragment(new MoviesFragment(), "ONE");
adapter.addFragment(new PhotosFragment(), "TWO");
adapter.addFragment(new SettingsFragment(), "THREE");
```

all are just empty fragments..thanks in advance

this is my main activity

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private NavigationView navigationView;
private DrawerLayout drawer;
private View navHeader;
private ImageView imgNavHeaderBg, imgProfile;
private TextView txtName, txtWebsite;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private FloatingActionButton fab;

// urls to load navigation header background image
// and profile image
private static final String urlNavHeaderBg = "http://api.androidhive.info/images/nav-menu-header-bg.jpg";
private static final String urlProfileImg = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/eCtE_G34M9ygdkmOpYvCag1vBARCmZwnVS6rS5t4JLzJ6QgQSBquM0nuTsCpLhYbKljoyS-txg";

// index to identify current nav menu item
public static int navItemIndex = 0;

// tags used to attach the fragments
private static final String TAG_HOME = "home";
private static final String TAG_PHOTOS = "photos";
private static final String TAG_MOVIES = "movies";
private static final String TAG_NOTIFICATIONS = "notifications";
private static final String TAG_SETTINGS = "settings";
public static String CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;

// toolbar titles respected to selected nav menu item
private String[] activityTitles;

// flag to load home fragment when user presses back key
private boolean shouldLoadHomeFragOnBackPress = true;
private Handler mHandler;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mHandler = new Handler();

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    // Navigation view header
    navHeader = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    txtName = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.name);
    txtWebsite = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.website);
    imgNavHeaderBg = (ImageView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.img_header_bg);
    imgProfile = (ImageView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.img_profile);

    // load toolbar titles from string resources
    activityTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_item_activity_titles);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    // load nav menu header data
    loadNavHeader();

    // initializing navigation menu
    setUpNavigationView();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        navItemIndex = 0;
        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
        loadHomeFragment();
    }
}

/***
 * Load navigation menu header information
 * like background image, profile image
 * name, website, notifications action view (dot)
 */
private void loadNavHeader() {
    // name, website
    txtName.setText("Ravi Tamada");
    txtWebsite.setText("www.androidhive.info");

    // loading header background image
    Glide.with(this).load(urlNavHeaderBg)
            .crossFade()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(imgNavHeaderBg);

    // Loading profile image
    Glide.with(this).load(urlProfileImg)
            .crossFade()
            .thumbnail(0.5f)
            .bitmapTransform(new CircleTransform(this))
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(imgProfile);

    // showing dot next to notifications label
    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(3).setActionView(R.layout.menu_dot);
}

/***
 * Returns respected fragment that user
 * selected from navigation menu
 */
private void loadHomeFragment() {
    // selecting appropriate nav menu item
    selectNavMenu();

    // set toolbar title
    setToolbarTitle();

    // if user select the current navigation menu again, don't do anything
    // just close the navigation drawer
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CURRENT_TAG) != null) {
        drawer.closeDrawers();

        // show or hide the fab button
        toggleFab();
        return;
    }

    // Sometimes, when fragment has huge data, screen seems hanging
    // when switching between navigation menus
    // So using runnable, the fragment is loaded with cross fade effect
    // This effect can be seen in GMail app
    Runnable mPendingRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // update the main content by replacing fragments
            Fragment fragment = getHomeFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                    android.R.anim.fade_out);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, CURRENT_TAG);
            fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }
    };

    // If mPendingRunnable is not null, then add to the message queue
    if (mPendingRunnable != null) {
        mHandler.post(mPendingRunnable);
    }

    // show or hide the fab button
    toggleFab();

    //Closing drawer on item click
    drawer.closeDrawers();

    // refresh toolbar menu
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

private Fragment getHomeFragment() {
    switch (navItemIndex) {
        case 0:
            // home
            HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
            return homeFragment;
        case 1:
            // photos
            PhotosFragment photosFragment = new PhotosFragment();
            return photosFragment;
        case 2:
            // movies fragment
            MoviesFragment moviesFragment = new MoviesFragment();
            return moviesFragment;
        case 3:
            // notifications fragment
            NotificationsFragment notificationsFragment = new NotificationsFragment();
            return notificationsFragment;

        case 4:
            // settings fragment
            SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
            return settingsFragment;
        default:
            return new HomeFragment();
    }
}

private void setToolbarTitle() {
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(activityTitles[navItemIndex]);
}

private void selectNavMenu() {
    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(navItemIndex).setChecked(true);
}

private void setUpNavigationView() {
    //Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

            //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
                case R.id.home:
                    navItemIndex = 0;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_photos:
                    navItemIndex = 1;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_PHOTOS;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_movies:
                    navItemIndex = 2;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_MOVIES;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_notifications:
                    navItemIndex = 3;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_NOTIFICATIONS;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_settings:
                    navItemIndex = 4;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_SETTINGS;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_about_us:
                    // launch new intent instead of loading fragment
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutUsActivity.class));
                    drawer.closeDrawers();
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_privacy_policy:
                    // launch new intent instead of loading fragment
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PrivacyPolicyActivity.class));
                    drawer.closeDrawers();
                    return true;
                default:
                    navItemIndex = 0;
            }

            //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
            if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
                menuItem.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                menuItem.setChecked(true);
            }
            menuItem.setChecked(true);

            loadHomeFragment();

            return true;
        }
    });


    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };

    //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
    drawer.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    //calling sync state is necessary or else your hamburger icon wont show up
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        return;
    }

    // This code loads home fragment when back key is pressed
    // when user is in other fragment than home
    if (shouldLoadHomeFragOnBackPress) {
        // checking if user is on other navigation menu
        // rather than home
        if (navItemIndex != 0) {
            navItemIndex = 0;
            CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
            loadHomeFragment();
            return;
        }
    }

    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

    // show menu only when home fragment is selected
    if (navItemIndex == 0) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    }

    // when fragment is notifications, load the menu created for notifications
    if (navItemIndex == 3) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.notifications, menu);
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_logout) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logout user!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }

    // user is in notifications fragment
    // and selected 'Mark all as Read'
    if (id == R.id.action_mark_all_read) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All notifications marked as read!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    // user is in notifications fragment
    // and selected 'Clear All'
    if (id == R.id.action_clear_notifications) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clear all notifications!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

// show or hide the fab
private void toggleFab() {
    if (navItemIndex == 0)
        fab.show();
    else
        fab.hide();
}
```

}

Comment: In that particular fragment layout you add tab and do.Follow this http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Comment: Use `TabLayout` for it

Comment: @AnshulTyagi  you mean inside home fragment need to use tab layout . thanks for reply

Comment: @SunishaSindhu what you shared tutorial he implemented those tabs in activity..how can use those features in fragment.can you help me.thanks for reply

Comment: yes. and use `ViewPager` also with`TabLayout` for redirecting to the corresponding fragments. And @SanthoshKumar for example I created [an example here of nested fragments](https://github.com/anshul90/WeekendTask/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/weekendtask/fragment/LowerMainFragment.java)

Comment: try with this solution, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35058819/android-tablayout-inside-fragment

Comment: @SunishaSindhu i tried what you said..working but one problem is there 
see first it will show defaultly home screen.so in this case its working i mean tabs are visible 

but i select some other menu item and again come back to home fragment tabs are not visible why??

thanks

Comment: Need to check your code.

Comment: so can i paste here or esle

Comment: Edit your question with code

Comment: ok thanks..i will update

Comment: hi @SunishaSindhu i updated can you check

Comment: wait.let me check

Comment: Explain your issue clearly please.You are properly replacing your fragment class na?

Comment: see, let's say when app starts by default its show home fragment because i implemented slide menu control

so in that home fragment only i implemented tabbed fragment

so now its working

but what is the problem is if i go to other fragment instead of home and again i will come back to home fragment those tabs are not visible only one time visible that is very first time.

if you really didnt under stand means i will update again

Comment: Can AnyBody Help me please

Comment: Share your main activity class where you are adding navigation drawer.

Comment: yes i shared @SunishaSindhu

Comment: try to add like this in your switch case fragment  with runnable,you need to replace the fragment

Comment: ok i will try @SunishaSindhu can you give some more clarity if its possible only