# How can I create a Fragment with a Tab View inside an item of an App Bar Menu?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

How can I insert in a Fragment (I suppose) a Tab View like this
[image: Tab View]

so when I click on "Misurazioni" item of the menu on the photo below it shows me the layout with the tabs 
[image: Menu]

Or are there any other ways to do it? I'd like to see tab view when I click on a menu item. Thanks

Comment: Have you used ViewPager with TabLayout?

Comment: this should help! https://stackoverflow.com/a/38037171/6142219