# TabLayout in fragment show empty white bar

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tablayout

Currently my application have a MainActivity with the toolbar and a framelayout used to display fragment.

Now I have a fragment with tablayout and viewpager. But the tablayout in this fragment shows an empty **whitebar** instead of the tab content. I am still able to swipe left and right to change viewpager content which is my other fragment but unable to view the tablayout.

So this is my fragment with tablayout and viewpager:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            android:fillViewport="true"/>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

```
class UploadPreviewFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_upload_preview, container, false)

        val viewPager = view.findViewById<ViewPager>(R.id.view_pager)
        val tabLayout = view.findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.tab_layout)

        val fragmentManager = UploadPagerAdapter(childFragmentManager)
        viewPager.adapter = fragmentManager
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(view_pager)

        return view
    }

}
```

My adapter calss:

```
class UploadPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {
    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> {
                UploadPdfFragment()
            }
            else -> {
                UploadImagesFragment()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return 2
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> {
                "Upload PDF"
            }
            else -> {
                "Upload Images"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And Screenshot for the tablayout:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mFWU.png

## EDIT

I have found the solution to my problem from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout. The problem cause by this is because the xml file, the tablayout should place inside the viewpager.

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:fillViewport="true"/>

    </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Check if childFragmentManager!=null.

Comment: checked, childFragmentManager is not null

Comment: Try below solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35058819/android-tablayout-inside-fragment

Comment: Thanks for the helps, i had found the solution from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout and has been updated to my post.

Answer (score -1):

change ParentFragmentManager to childFargmentManager in Adapter definition

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).