# Android TabLayout inside NavigationDrawer with Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer, android-tablayout

I am using NavigationDrawer with Fragments. Now I have 8 menu's in my navigation Drawer but I want to use tab layout in only two or 3 fragments.

[Navigation_Menu Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFJxg.png)

I am using tab layout in a fragment whose name in the menu is department.
So I am using ViewPager and PagerAdaper so do I need to write the code in Main Activity or fragmentClass.java

I was having trouble using Code Snippet on Stack Overflow so here are the gist's of my code:

1. Mainactivity.java -
   https://gist.github.com/Faizi-alpha/c03df8bc9795c10e3c97d68d9f82c6cb
2. Fragment_Department.java -
   https://gist.github.com/Faizi-alpha/e166f914727af88fb70e084f67f80fa5
3. FragmentDepartmentView.xml - https://gist.github.com/Faizi-alpha/238386596515661bd00043b61966220a

Where Should I write the Java PagerAdapter and ViewPager code? I tried coding it in DepartmentFragment.java but I am not getting "getSupportFragmentManager()" in this class.

Do I need to handle each fragment in mainActivity.java ??

Comment: have you tried to use `getChildFragmentManager()`?

Comment: No, I dont know that

Comment: Since you want the TabLayout only inside a specific fragment, then it must be inside that fragment

Comment: Idk if it's a typo, but in the gist, FragmentDepartment.java is different from its public class fragment_department. Aren't you getting errors because of it?

Comment: Also, your FragmentDepartmentView.xml is different from the one you are inflating inside the Fragment, which is fragment_department

Comment: Instead of ```getSupportFragmentManager()``` use ```getChildFragmentManager()```. Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35058819/android-tablayout-inside-fragment

Comment: Thanks Price ! You are right. getChildFragmentManager() does the job.

Comment: @DionSaputra Thanks a lot mate , you told me already but I couldn't get it . Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use getChildFragmentManager() instead of getSupportFragmentManager().